# I am trying to integrate SAML2.0 with ColdFusion 10 Standard

Tags: java, coldfusion, saml-2.0

I am trying to integrate SAML with ColdFusion 10 Standard. I am using sample code from https://github.com/anthony-id/cfSAML

The issue is I keep getting  java.lang.NullPointerException when

```
var transforms = variables.TransformsClass.init(assertionNode.item(0).getOwnerDocument());
```

is executed.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<cffunction name="signSAML" output="false" access="private">
<cfargument name="samlAssert">
<cfargument name="assertionId">
<cfscript>
var samlAssertionXML = arguments.samlAssert;
//injest the xml
writedump(samlAssertionXML);
var samlAssertionElement = samlAssertionXML.getDocumentElement();
var samlAssertionDocument = samlAssertionElement.GetOwnerDocument();
var samlAssertion = samlAssertionDocument.getFirstChild();

var conditionsNode = samlAssertionElement.getElementsByTagName('saml:Conditions');
var assertionNode = samlAssertionElement.getElementsByTagName('saml:Assertion');
var statusNode = samlAssertionElement.getElementsByTagName('samlp:Status');
var signature = getSignature(samlAssertionDocument);
//set up signature transforms
var transforms = variables.TransformsClass.init(assertionNode.item(0).getOwnerDocument());

abort;
transforms.addTransform(variables.transformEnvStr);
transforms.addTransform(variables.transformOmitCommentsStr);
switch(getSAMLVersion()) {
case "1":
// Insert signature before statusNode
samlAssertion.insertBefore(signature.getElement(),statusNode.item(0));
break;
default:
// Insert signature AFTER issuer node
assertionNode.item(0).insertBefore(signature.getElement(),conditionsNode.item(0));
break;
}
//set up the signature
signature.addDocument("###arguments.assertionId#",transforms);
//optionally include the cert and public key
signature.addKeyInfo(getKeystore().getCert());
signature.addKeyInfo(getKeystore().getPublickey());
signature.sign(getKeystore().getPrivateKey());
return samlAssertionXML;
</cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Below is the StackTrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.getImplementingClass(Unknown
>   Source) at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms.addTransform(Unknown
>   Source) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:508) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2465) at
>   cfSAMLService2ecfc133932769$funcSIGNSAML.runFunction(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\PPNPFTEST\SAMLTEST\com\SAMLService.cfc:211)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
>   coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2659) at
>   cfSAMLService2ecfc133932769$funcGETSAML.runFunction(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\PPNPFTEST\SAMLTEST\com\SAMLService.cfc:56)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
>   coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:444) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2432) at
>   cftest2ecfm775253356.runPage(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\PPNPFTEST\SAMLTEST\test.cfm:18)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244) at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444) at
>   coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at
>   coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64) at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:443)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>   at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>   at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at
>   coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30) at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at
>   coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>   at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at
>   coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at
>   coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
>   coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at
>   coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:204) at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Here is what is returned when dumping assertionNode.item(0).getOwnerDoument()
[image: writedump (assertionNode.item(0).getOwnerDoument())]

Comment: I have used it, but .. can you post the full trace? Without it, it is not clear whether the NPE is coming from assertionNode.item(0).getOwnerDocument() or the constructor call. Also, did you dump the argument to see if it is null?

Comment: Leigh, I posted the full trace as requested. Thank you for your help - I really need it.

Comment: Do a dump of `assertionNode.item(0).getOwnerDocument()` and see what it has

Comment: James, I posted the result of assertion.item(0).getOwnerDocument() dump. It just lists the class name, namespace and the methods nothing else. In fact I tried dumping samlAssertionElement, samlAssertionDocument and samlAssertion and all return similarly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that at least confirms the NPE is probably caused by something in the initialization of the TransformsClass. Unfortunately, I do not have time to try it out right now, but hopefully James or someone else will chime in with other ideas in the mean time ...

Comment: Guys I really need your help.